# Attempting to access link to state within another component results in a typerror where state in undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am attempting to pass down state via the `<Link>` component as such to my `NextPage` component:

```
<Link to={{pathname: `/job-run-id/${item.job_run_id}`, state: { prevPath: location.pathname }}}
>
{item.job_run_id}
</Link>
```

The NextPage component is being rendered via the following route:

```
<Route exact path="/job-run-id/:jobID">
   <NextPage />
</Route>
```

The `NextPage` component is setup as follows and just receives the `props`:

```
const NextPage = (props) => (
  <div>
    <p>previous path is: {props.location.state.prevPath}</p>
  </div>
);
```

Attempting to run the above code results in the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`

Unfortunately I can't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: There is an issue with this approach . For example if you click on the link and go the next page and do a refresh your app will break . Also is your NextPage is rendered via <Route /> ? . From the error it looks like props.location is undefined .

Comment: Please update your question to include how `NextPage` is rendered and receiving the [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props).

Comment: @Shyam the NextPage component is being rendered via a route and I have updated my code. When you say that `props.location` is undefined, sorry, but where/how do I set this up?

Comment: @DrewReese - have updated code to include how the `NextPage` component is being rendered but unsure what you mean wrt how it is receiving the route props? I am just passing in props as a parameter. Please note that react-router is new to me and still trying to grasp it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the `NextPage` component to receive the [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) (*`history`, `location`, and `match`*) it needs to be rendered by one of `render`, `component`, or `children` function props.

[Route render methods](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods)

[component](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component)

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/job-run-id/:jobID"
  component={NextPage}
/>
```

[render](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func)

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/job-run-id/:jobID"
  render={routeProps => <NextPage {...routeProps} />}
/>
```

[children function](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/children-func)

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/job-run-id/:jobID"
  children={routeProps => (
    <NextPage {...routeProps} />
  )}
/>
```

For your use case, and since you aren't passing additional props to `NextPage`, I suggest using the `component` method to render your component on the route.

An alternative if you don't want to change how `NextPage` is rendered is you decorate it with the [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component to have the route props injected into it. Export the decorated `NextPage` component.

```
default export withRouter(NextPage);
```

Or since `NextPage` is a function component, use the [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) React hook to get to the route state.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const NextPage = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  return (
    <div>
      <p>previous path is: {state.prevPath}</p>
    </div>
  )
};
```